# Reusable relationships

Tags: orm, silverstripe, convention

What is the best/standard way to create a relationship you can add to multiple dataobjects? using a DataExtension you can create a has_many like so

```
public static $has_many = array('Links' => 'Link');
```

but then in the mirrored has_one relation in Link you would have to explicitly list the classes using the DataExtension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `many_many` instead of as `has_many`.

Comment: But then the has_one on Link would become $belongs_many_many so that wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Do you need the reverse relationship though? In most cases like these you don't, so you don't need to provide the `belongs_many_many`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the File and Image classes to get an idea of how the framework does this. The framework's unit tests for those classes will also provide an indication for how they are set up and used.